# how do I access only specific array values in this PHP array

Tags: php, arrays, apple-push-notifications

I get this php array back from Apples APNS feedback service:

```
array(4) { 
    [0]=> string(64) "abc123" 
    [1]=> string(64) "def456"
    [2]=> array(3) { 
            ["timestamp"]=> int(1426717247) ["length"]=> int(32) ["devtoken"]=> string(64) "xyz987" 
    }
    [3]=> array(3) { 
            ["timestamp"]=> int(1426717247) ["length"]=> int(32) ["devtoken"]=> string(64) "xyz987" 
    }
}
```

How do I use php to loop over this array, and build a comma separated string of only the array elements that contain 'devtoken' item / value(s)?

UPDATE:  I had been trying to do it with implode, and that may be do-able, but what I ended up using was based on the answer from Steve and looks like the following:

```
$deldevidstring='';
foreach($feedback_tokens as $element){
    if(is_array($element) && isset($element['devtoken'])){
        $deldevidstring .= $element['devtoken'] .',' ;
    }
}
if(strlen(trim($deldevidstring)) > 0){
   echo trim("delete these... " . $deldevidstring, ',');
}
```

Comment: Have you tried something?

Comment: What you have there is an array (numeric) of mixed type elements. Some are strings and others are arrays (associative). Loop over each element of the parent array and check to see if each element is an array. If it is, then check the sub-array to see if it contains a key named "devtoken". If it does, append the value associated with that key to a string.

Answer (score 1, accepted):

iterate the array and build your string:

```
$string='';
foreach($array as $element){
    if(isset($element['devtoken'])){
        $string .=',' . $element['devtoken'];
    }
}
echo trim($string, ',');
```

Or implode a filtered array:

```
$string = implode(',', 
              array_filter(
                  array_map(
                      function($element){
                          return $element['devtoken']
                      }, 
                      $array
                  )
              )
          );
```

Comment: awesome.... thanks, that first bit of code worked brilliantly... I had been tinkering with implode, but butchered it horribly.  Really appreciate your feedback / input on this.

Answer (score 0):

Check this out:

```
<?php

$str = "";

foreach($array as $arr)
{
    if(is_array($arr))
    {
        if(array_key_exists('devtoken', $arr))
        {
            $str = implode(",", $arr)."\n";
        }
    }
}

?>
```

Answer (score 0):

Assuming you have set $records = the array you got back:

```
$string = '';

foreach ($records as $record) {
    if (isset($array['devtoken'])) {
        $string .= $array['devtoken'] . ', ';
    }
}
$string = substr($string, 0, -2);
echo $string;
```

There are no doubt more elegant ways to do this but for short and quick this seems to work.

Answer (score 0):

No need to loop.  With PHP >= 5.5.0:

```
$result = implode(',', array_column($array, 'devtoken'));
```

For earlier versions without `array_column`:

```
$result = implode(',', array_filter(array_map(function($v) { return $v['devtoken']; }, $array)));
```

Comment: This works, but i dont know why you do not get an undefined index notice, as not all elements passed to the closure will have a 'devtoken' key? Is this documented somewhere? Also, you might want to handle the empty elements.

Comment: @AbraCadaver still will prove useful and good to know, thanks